# Merging Date and Time columns into DATETIME column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to concat two columns `DATE` and `TIME` into one column `DATETIME`.

These columns are already existing but they are in different tables.

The structure is like :

**TABLE 1 :** `column_datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)`

**TABLE 2 :** `column_date (YYYY-MM-DD), column_time(HH-MM-SS).`

I need to update the table 1 and I tried this :

```
UPDATE table1 SET column_datetime = CONCAT('table2.column_date', ' ', 'table2.column_time');
```

But it says :

> Incorrect datetime value : 'table2.column_date table2.column_time for
>   column 'column_datetime' at row 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE table1, table2
SET column_datetime = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(table2.column_date, ' ', table2.column_time), '%Y-%c-%e %T')
WHERE table1.FK_ID = table2.ID ;
```

Comment: I've tried it but it says : Incorrect time value : '15:50:32' for function str_to_date.
I also tried with "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s" instead of '%Y-%c-%e %r' and it says the same error : Incorrect time value : '2008-08-11 15:50:32' for function str_to_date

Comment: That iss because of 24 hour notation. Use %R instead of %r. I have updated the code

Comment: So may i update the answer, so that it would be useful to others?